# Run multiple virtual Android devices(emulators) simultaneously

Tags: android

I need to run multiple (up to 70-100) virtual devices at the same time for test on one server.
Is it possible?
Does anyone know such software to do that?
It would be perfect if it would support some GPGPU technologies like OpenCL.

Comment: "Is it possible?" -- the only limit that I know of with the Android emulator is available RAM, though I would expect running that many emulator instances to seriously tax any server's CPU. "Does anyone know such software to do that?" -- what are you expecting this "software" to do, exactly?

Comment: Software should work as AVD manager from Android SDK or Genymotion and it should support modern GPGPU to run a lot of instances in parallel. That is what I expect from it. But it seems that there is not such soft yet.